# Optimal strategy for deleting a record from a table with child relationships to the n'th degree

Tags: database

Given a database that contains a table Foo. Foo has child relationships with several other tables, which in their turn have child relationships with even more tables. In short, Foo has child relationships to the n'th degree.

Now lets say that we want to delete a record from Foo. Before we could do this, we would have to determine an optimal strategy to delete all child (grandchild, etc...) records to avoid tripping over foreign key constraints.

**Is there a tool that I can feed my database schema, tell it that I want to delete a Foo record, and it will calculate the optimal delete strategy for me?** So I can take this strategy and implement it in my business logic.

*Elaboration:* As noted in the comments ON CASCADE DELETE would be a perfect fit for the above scenario. However, I neglected to say that Foo is connected to some of its descendants via multiple paths. This makes cascading not an option, for MS SQL Server at least. The ORM we use is LINQ to SQL, which also has no support for cascading scenarios. So we have a situation in which it is not so obvious in what order a record from Foo and all of its descendants should be deleted, and which order would be most optimal. This would require some puzzling, and Foo is not the only table for which this needs doing of course :-) Hence, my question if there is a tool that will analyze this for me.

Comment: Did you consider `ON DELETE CASCADE`? Do that, and adding more "child" tables won't require any changes to application code.

Comment: Are you using a specific database engine or is this a general question?

Comment: On db schema level, `on delete cascade` is the most efficient variant. If you can't use it, an ORM, like SQLAlchemy, can handle [the cascade deletions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#cascades) for you.

Comment: At above commenters: see the elaboration I added to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in an algorithmic way (as compared to telling you a tool that will do this), you want to do a topological sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

The optimal algorithm is O(|E|+|V|) - where edges E is the number of child references and vertices V is the number of records.  (You can probably say that a vertex is actually a table if you want to presume that all child references exist)

The topological sort will then give you the ordering of records to delete (or the order of tables).